# Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type in DotNetNuke

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I was given a DNN project to work on, but the initial installation and configuration are very unfamiliar to me. Now, I downloaded the solution from SVN, updated the conn string, tried to run and I'm getting this error:

[image]

What's wrong with the application and what do I need to change?

Comment: Are you downloading the source version?  If you are just creating a DNN project, you should be using the Install version.

If you use the source version, you have to compile it before you use it.  Only use the source version if you want to change/debug the DNN Core.

Comment: I downloaded that version from svn repository from previous developer, not from the official dnn site

Answer (score 0):

there are some missing dlls in bin directory that is causing this issue. Go to properties of dotnetnuke.dll and download the matching version from dotnetnuke.codeplex.com. Extract it locally and compare bin folder and move missing files to fix this.

Also remember to add your local url in portalAlias table to get working locally.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is the properties window for dotnetnuke.dll http://i.gyazo.com/64b0fb68e7848ee1ca996fccbe1e1960.png

Comment: You are using 4.9.0.85 build of dnn, download new install zip from this link: http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/releases/view/32336